# Push data into keys of json array

Tags: javascript, json

guys i know it is dummy questions but i tried alot and cant reach .. i want to push data into json array but i want to make the function to work on any array without setting constant keys names and columns .. my code works well on certain array json .. but i cant make it work on any one

```
function insertRow() {
  var i = 1;
  var val = document.getElementsByName("input" + i)[0].value;
  grid.data.push({"lname" : val, "fname" : val, "age" : val,"feedback" : val});
  i++;
}
```

dont want to call the keys by its name and want to make it work on any number of columns
the json array

```
var json = [ {
        "lname" : "lname1",
        "fname" : "fname1",
        "age" : 10,
        "feedback" : "feedback1"
    }, {
        "lname" : "lname2",
        "fname" : "fname2",
        "age" : 90,
        "feedback" : "feedback2"
    }, {
        "lname" : "lname3",
        "name" : "fname3",
        "age" : 30,
        "feedback" : "feedback3"
    }, {
        "lname" : "lname4",
        "fname" : "fname4",
        "age" : 50,
        "feedback" : "feedback4"
    }, {
        "lname" : "lname5",
        "fname" : "fname5",
        "age" : 55,
        "feedback" : "feedback5"
    }, {
        "lname" : "lname6",
        "fname" : "fname6",
        "age" : 68,
        "feedback" : "feedback6"
    }];
```

Comment: from where you are getting your key names and how are they related to input value?

Comment: the same names in my json array

Comment: @andy plz have a look

Comment: Ideally `{"lname" : val, "fname" : val, "age" : val,"feedback" : val}` should be in a function like `computeObject(val){return {"lname" : val, "fname" : val, "age" : val,"feedback" : val}}` and use it in `array.push(computeObject(value))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if you wish to compute objects with different keys but same value and what to make this generic you can try something like this:

```js
function computeObject(keys, value){
  var _tmp = {};
  keys.forEach(function(k){ _tmp[k]=value;});
  return _tmp;
}

function main(){
  var k1 = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
  var k2 = ["t1", "t2", "t3"];
  var v1 = 10;
  var v2 = "foo";
  print(computeObject(k1,v1));
  print(computeObject(k2,v2));
}

function print(obj){
  document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj,0,4) + "</pre> <br/>");
}

main();
```